# Intercepting Android Menu button

Tags: android

I have an app in which I want to display my own menu activity when the user presses the menu button. I am using the onCreateOptionsMenu method to launch my activity, returning false so that no menu is shown.  This is my code:

```
Intent intentMenu = new Intent(this, ActivityMenu.class);
startActivityForResult(intentMenu, 0);
return false;
```

This works, but only the first time the menu button is pressed.  I understand this method is only called once.  How can I get it to be called every time the user presses the menu button?  Or should I be going for a different approach?

Answer (score 5):

Do not use onCreateOptionsMenu(), wrong place. Here is how you do it by overriding onKeyDOwn() method in your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityMenu.class), 0);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown( keyCode, event );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create your menu class
look like this:

```
public class GlobalMenu extends Activity

{

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 

{

       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

       inflater.inflate(R.menu.global_menu, menu);

       return true;

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

{

    switch(item.getItemId())

    {

        case R.id.GlobalSettings:

                           // Write code to perform action
            break;

        case R.id.Globalrefresh:

                           // Write code to perform action
            break;

        case R.id.Globalexit:

                           // Write code to perform action
            break;

        default:

    }

    return true;

}



}
```

Now extend this class from your main Activity in which you wont to show menu , when you click on menu button.

And create .xml file look like :

Comment: Sorry Dhaval, I think I may not have made myself clear.  I want to display a new screen (based on ActivityMenu) when the user presses the menu button, I do not want to use the default menu system.

Comment: This is not show android default menu. It show the custom menu which u wont.

Comment: If you want to launch an activity as soon as the `Menu` button is pressed, do all the launching stuff inside the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method. I am not sure how standard or good this practice is, but it should work

Comment: Sheik, I was doing that, but it was only getting called once.  Anyway, I have now resolved the problem by handling the menu press in the onKeyDown event, and launching my activity from there.

Comment: @NiMuSi: perhaps write your final comment as an answer as this seems to work for my context too.